# How to migrate one Mysql Table into two Mysql tables

Tags: mysql, reference, migration, pentaho, kettle

I want to transform this (MySql) tables:

```
distribution_receipt
    id_distribution_receipt
    receipt_number
    period
    expiration
    total_amount
    id_client
    (other fields)

general_receipt
    id_general_receipt
    period
    total_amount
    receipt_number
    direction
    tel
    (other fields)
```

Into

```
receipt
    id_receipt
    total_amount
    receipt_number
    period

distribution_receipt
    id_distribution_receipt
    receipt_number
    expiration
    id_client
    id_receipt (fk)

general_receipt
    id_general_receipt
    tel
    direction
    id_receipt (fk)
```

So, how can i do this, and keep reference with new "receipt" table?

i prefered to do it manually with mysql statements, but i'm also using pentaho-Kettle data integration tool for migration.

Comment: not able to understand your question.
if you want to laod 2 tables data into 1 table then you can simply create connection, map the fields and load it.

Comment: create table receipt select .... from distribution_receipt

Comment: i want to split receipt table, i want to do a hierarchy, receipt is the "father" of that hierarchy , so when i create distribution_receipt i.e. , i also need receipt_id to keep the reference between them

Answer (score 0):

This is really quite easy. You can split your streams in two by simply dragging from one step to two different locations and selecting "copy" not "distribute." Then simply use two table output or insert/update steps and populate two tables.

Here's a similar post from the pentaho forum:

```
http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?74743-How-to-split-a-stream-into-two-table-outputs
```

Comment: Sounds good, but i want to do a hierarchy, receipt is the "father" of that hierarchy , so when i create distribution_receipt i.e. , i also need receipt_id to keep the reference between them. I don't know if it's clear, i could explain a little more if it's not

Comment: Sure the more details the better. I'm pretty sure you can get the IDs you need... and in the worst possible case simply use look ups to grab them from the DB.

Comment: Did you get this? I really think it's pretty simple to do the way I was saying.